# Custom View Helpers are not Getting Loaded on Server

Tags: zend-framework, view-helpers

I have some custom form elements that use custom view helpers in my Zend Framework project.  They get loaded and work properly on development machine but when I move the project over to my EC2 server they don't get loaded.

From application.ini:

```
resources.view.helperPath.Custom_View_Helper_ = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Custom/View/Helper/"
```

Error returned by server:

```
Warning: Exception caught by form: Plugin by name 'Multiselect' was not found in the registry; 
used paths: 
Application_Views_Helpers_Fields_: /home/user/hippo/application/views/helpers/fields/ 
Application_Views_Helpers_: /home/user/hippo/application/views/helpers/ 
Custom_View_Helper_: /home/user/hippo/application/../library/Custom/View/Helper/ 
Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/home/user/hippo/application/views/helpers/ Stack 
Trace: 
#0 /home/user/hippo/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1182): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('Multiselect') 
#1 /home/user/hippo/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(618): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'multiselect') 
#2 /home/user/hippo/library/Zend/Form/Decorator/ViewHelper.php(241): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('multiselect') 
#3 /home/user/hippo/library/Zend/Form/Element.php(2043): Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper->render('') 
#4 /home/user/hippo/library/Zend/Form/Decorator/FormElements.php(111): Zend_Form_Element->render() 
#5 /home/user/hippo/library/Zend/ in /home/user/hippo/library/Zend/Form.php on line 2925
```

What could cause this to work on my dev machine but not on EC2?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  My dev machine is a Mac and EC2 is running Linux.  I had to change `public $helper='multiselect'` to `public $helper='multiSelect'` so it would search for the file name `MultiSelect.php` instead of `Multiselect.php` when searching for the view helper.